# Solving $T(n) = 3T(n-1)$

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

How is the constant before the $T$ important to the result from $T(n)$

I know that

\begin{equation*}
T(n) = T(n-1) + 3 \Rightarrow \theta(n)~\text{and}~T(n) = T(n-1) + n \Rightarrow \theta(n^2)
\end{equation*}

and so i don´t know if the 3 before $T$ from $T(n) = 3T(n-1)$ is an $\theta(3^n)$ or if the constant $3$ isn't important and the result is $\theta(n)$.

Comment: $T(n) = 3T(n-1) = 9T(n-2) = \dots = 3^{n-1} T(1) = \Theta(3^n)$. $\Theta(n)$ and $\Theta(3^n)$ are dramatically different asymptotics.

Comment: Scenario A. I am getting old, so every day I need 3 seconds more than the day before to finish my meals. Scenario B. I am getting old, so my meals take three times the time I needed the day before. Do you think that the time needed to finish my Christmas dinner will be almost the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm and setting $S(n)=\log(T(n))$, the recurrence is

$$S(n)=S(n-1)+\log(3)\to\Theta(n).$$

Then
$$T(n)\to\Theta(\exp(n)),$$ wich grows much faster.